# Expose useNuxtApp() to every page and component

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

In every component i have to declare useNuxtApp() like:

```js
<script setup>
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()

</script>
```

Is there a way just to "auto declare" it in every page/component ?

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing what are you trying to achieve when using the `useNuxtApp` composable?

Comment: Hi! In this case im trying to access nuxt2Context without havong to declare it every time... i'm using nuxt bridge.